# MySQL: Get character-set of database or table or column?

Tags: sql, mysql, unicode, character-encoding, collation

What is the (default) charset for:

- MySQL database
- MySQL table
- MySQL column

Comment: For tables and columns, simply use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628217/how-can-i-figure-out-the-default-charset-collation-in-my-mysql

Answer (score 930):

Here's how I'd do it -

For Schemas (or Databases - they are synonyms):

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE schema_name = "mydatabasename";
```

For Tables:

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "mydatabasename"
  AND T.table_name = "tablename";
```

For Columns:

```
SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_schema = "mydatabasename"
  AND table_name = "tablename"
  AND column_name = "columnname";
```

Comment: Should be noted that information_schema is only in MySQL 5 onwards I believe.

Comment: As far as I can tell the closest you can get to retrieving column specific character set information in MySQL < 5 is to do SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tableName

Comment: This answer was very helpful, but if you want to trouble shoot a character_set / collation issue you would probably also need to check connection character_set, client_character_set etc... : 

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';

Comment: the table operation returns "Empty set (0.00 sec)" for me

Answer (score 539):

For **columns**:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Hello, this is the future speaking! For anyone checking this answer, this method only shows Collation, rather than charset. I believe this changed at MySQL 5. (See answer with more points for a better method).

Comment: @fideloper, **With the collation you can tell the charset.** That is because the first part of collation includes the charset, e.g. if the collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`, the charset can't be anything else besides `latin1`. If the collation is `utf8mb4_general_ci`, the charset can't be anything else besides `utf8mb4`.

Comment: This tells you the table character set.  It doesn't tell you the character set of tables created in the future when no character set is specified in the create table syntax (you'll need the schema character set for that).

Answer (score 240):

For **databases**:

```
USE your_database_name;
show variables like "character_set_database";
-- or:
-- show variables like "collation_database";
```

Cf. [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-database.html).  And check out the MySQL manual

Comment: This only answers 1/3 of the question.

Comment: @TobyJ, I don't see you complaining at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805510/632951

Comment: what does cf stands for?
link does not exist though. @Pacerier

Comment: This should be merged in the top answer. It really helped me.

Comment: @YannisDran: "cf." is an abbreviation for Latin "confer" = "bring together" =  "compare". It is often used more generally to mean "see".

Answer (score 194):

**For all the databases** you have on the server:

```
mysql> SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 'database', default_character_set_name 'charset', DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME 'collation' FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+---------+--------------------+
| database                   | charset | collation          |
+----------------------------+---------+--------------------+
| information_schema         | utf8    | utf8_general_ci    |
| my_database                | latin1  | latin1_swedish_ci  |
...
+----------------------------+---------+--------------------+
```

---

For a **single Database**:

```
mysql> USE my_database;
mysql> show variables like "character_set_database";
```

Output:

```
    +----------------------------+---------+
    | Variable_name              |  Value  |
    +----------------------------+---------+
    | character_set_database     |  latin1 | 
    +----------------------------+---------+
```

---

Getting the collation **for Tables**:

```
mysql> USE my_database;
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME LIKE 'my_tablename';
```

OR - will output the complete SQL for create table:

`mysql> show create table my_tablename`

---

Getting the collation of **columns**:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM my_tablename;
```

output:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------------+ ....
| field   | type         | collation          |
+---------+--------------+--------------------+ ....
| id      | int(10)      | (NULL)             |
| key     | varchar(255) | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| value   | varchar(255) | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+---------+--------------+--------------------+ ....
```

Comment: What version of mysql show this output for `type` ? I have mysql 5.7.9 and `type` show the `data type` of the column not the `character set`. Some like  `int(10)` `varchar(255)` ... etc and not `utf8`

Comment: My output shows `type` as the `data type` as well @MTK, perhaps above is a copy paste error in the "output:" section.

Answer (score 75):

For **tables**:

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` will list all the tables.

Filter using:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS where name like 'table_123';
```

Comment: Please note.
The collation shown in the show table status is not the character set of the table.
The collation tells you how the characters are sorted / compared. e.g. utf8_bin_ci compares data without regarding the case (case insensitive, so "m" and "M" are the same), utf8_bin_cs compares with case sensitivity (so "m" and "M" are distinct).
This is not the same as the character set of a table.

Comment: @Daan, Stop spreading misinformation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is/1049776#comment52112197_4805510 , with the collation you can tell the charset.

Answer (score 71):

To see default collation of the database:

```
USE db_name;
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

To see collation of the table:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS where name like 'table_name';
```

To see collation of the columns:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;
```

To see the default character set of a table

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

Comment: Like this! As per: [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html)

Answer (score 45):

For **databases**:

Just use these commands:

```
USE db_name;
SELECT @@character_set_database;
-- or:
-- SELECT @@collation_database;
```

Comment: This is the answer from the official mysql doc. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html

Answer (score 40):

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
       TABLE_NAME,
       CCSA.CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS DEFAULT_CHAR_SET,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       COLUMN_TYPE,
       C.CHARACTER_SET_NAME
  FROM information_schema.TABLES AS T
  JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS AS C USING (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)
  JOIN information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY AS CCSA
       ON (T.TABLE_COLLATION = CCSA.COLLATION_NAME)
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=SCHEMA()
   AND C.DATA_TYPE IN ('enum', 'varchar', 'char', 'text', 'mediumtext', 'longtext')
 ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA,
          TABLE_NAME,
          COLUMN_NAME
;
```

Comment: Very nice, Eric.  Just paste that code into the mysql command line, hit return and you get the character set of every column in every table in every database :)

Comment: @JerryKrinock You get every columns of the current database and nothing if no database is selected.

Answer (score 36):

I always just look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydatabase.mytable`.

For the database, it appears you need to look at `SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA`.

Comment: in mysql databases can have default character sets

Comment: `select default_character_set_name from information_schema.schemata` is not enough because you can't tell which row correlate with which database. Use `select default_character_set_name,schema_name from information_schema.schemata` or simply: **`select*from information_schema.schemata`**.

Comment: I used

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = '<database-name>' \G;`

And it worked great :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

For **tables** and **columns**:

```
show create table your_table_name
```

Comment: It tells you the full SQL that would be used to create the table as it currently stands, which should include it's character set.

Comment: Also, if the column doesn't state a particular charset, then it is using the table's default charset.

Answer (score 20):

For **databases**:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 'database', default_character_set_name 'charset', DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME 'collation' FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

Example output:

```
mysql> SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 'database', default_character_set_name 'charset', DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME 'collation' FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
+----------------------------+---------+--------------------+
| database                   | charset | collation          |
+----------------------------+---------+--------------------+
| information_schema         | utf8    | utf8_general_ci    |
| drupal_demo1               | utf8    | utf8_general_ci    |
| drupal_demo2               | utf8    | utf8_general_ci    |
| drupal_demo3               | utf8    | utf8_general_ci    |
| drupal_demo4               | utf8    | utf8_general_ci    |
| drupal_demo5               | latin1  | latin1_swedish_ci  |

...

+----------------------------+---------+--------------------+
55 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Isn't this a repeat of [the first answer on top](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1049958/632951) and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1049753/632951 ?

Comment: @Pacerier did you actually compare my answer to these properly?

Answer (score 16):

For **databases**:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE "DB_NAME_HERE";
```

---

In creating a Database (MySQL), default character set/collation is always LATIN, instead that you have selected a different one on initially creating your database

Comment: [Citation needed](http://xkcd.com/285) for *"default character set/collation is always LATIN"* in MySQL.

Comment: Citation needed? Have you ever used a MySQL database? Everyone knows that the default character set/collation is `latin1_swedish_ci` because Monty Widenius, the creator of MySQL, is Swedish and was not thinking as Big Picture as he should have when he started.

Answer (score 5):

As many wrote earlier, SHOW FULL COLUMNS should be the preferred method to get column information.
What's missing is a way to get charset after that without reaching metadata tables directly:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM my_table WHERE Field = 'my_field'
SHOW COLLATION WHERE Collation = 'collation_you_got'
```

Answer (score 4):

For database :
`USE db_name;  SELECT @@character_set_database;`

Answer (score 1):

Just cheat sheet for somebody who wants to get table name, column name, and character set together for multiple tables all at once.

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE table_schema = "MY_DATABASE"
  AND table_name in ("tableFoo", "tableBar");
```

The expected output:

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
    -> WHERE table_schema = "MY_DATABASE"
    ->   AND table_name in ("tableFoo", "tableBar");
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME         | character_set_name |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| tableFoo   | foo1                | NULL               |
| tableFoo   | foo2                | utf8mb4            |
| tableFoo   | foo3                | NULL               |
| tableFoo   | foo4                | utf8mb4            |
| tableFoo   | foo5                | NULL               |
| tableBar   | bar1                | NULL               |
| tableBar   | bar2                | NULL               |
| tableBar   | bar3                | utf8mb4            |
| tableBar   | bar4                | NULL               |
| tableBar   | bar5                | NULL               |
| tableBar   | bar6                | NULL               |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

show global variables where variable_name like 'character_set_%' or variable_name like 'collation%'

Answer (score -2):

When creating a new database, some necessary table will be generated

in "information_schema" this path

"COLUMNS"->about columns

[image: 1]

"TABLES"->about table

[image: 2]

For example, if you need to see all the column names and types in a table

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_TYPE FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```

Comment: The answer would be easier to see if the text from the images was embedded as text in the answer.

Comment: The answer would be easier to see if the text from the images was embedded as text in the answer.