# How to find out the charset of a database and table with PHPmyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there a way in PHPMyAdmin to find out the charset of a table and/or a database?

The only thing that ist shown, is the collation. But as far as I understood, the collation only tells the database how to compare the data, and the charset tells the database how to store the data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try writing a SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S
WHERE schema_name = "myDataBase";
```

You might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql) and the comments on [this ressoure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-database.html);

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also find it by just looking at the collation name itself in most of the cases. Say the collation name is "latin1_swedish_ci" then the character set for the database is "latin1".