# Latin1 character set table is not encoding characters in Latin1 Encoding

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

The mysql table that I am inserting it into (let's call it foo) is latin1 character encoded (shown via the command shown [How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql)) and my database has the following result after show variables:

```
| character_set_client                    | latin1                                                                                    |
| character_set_connection                | latin1                                                                                    |
| character_set_database                  | latin1
```

In foo I have an entry stored in a varchar(255) col with the string foo® and when I view it in hex it shows that it is encoded in utf8 (666F6FC2AE). Running a select query from the mysql prompt shows me foo®. However when I insert the same string encoded in latin1 666F6FAE I get a foo� when I run a select in the same mysql command prompt. Why is it that I have utf8 encoded data in my latin1 table and why am I not able to insert latin1 encoded data into my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command line client seems to use UTF-8 for display/input/output. `666F6FC2AE` is not a UTF-8 encoded value in a latin-1 column, it's the latin-1 code for "fooÂ®". Getting this back from the database, your CLI interprets the latin-1 data as UTF-8, displaying "foo®".

To illustrate:

- CLI operates in UTF-8
- you enter "foo®" on the CLI, which is `66 6F 6F C2AE`
- database connection is set to latin-1
- database interprets input as latin-1, thinks you want to store "fooÂ®"
- column encoding is latin-1, no problem, database stores "fooÂ®"
- you fetch data from database, all latin-1, you get back `66 6F 6F C2 AE`
- CLI interprets this as UTF-8, displays "foo®"

You need to set your connection encoding to `utf8`, since your client sends UTF-8. That, or convince your CLI to operate in Latin-1, which may be harder/less convenient/causing more side effects.