# What should be the data type to store Currency Symbol in Django Models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a Django model that relates to the currency with fields like currency name, currency code and currency symbol.

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    currency_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    currency_symbol = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The currency_symbol field will hold a symbol for a particular currency, for example "€".

However when I'm trying to save the model, I'm getting the following exception,

```
django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'currency_symbol' at row 1")
```

So what should be the correct datatype?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14318730/1472458

Comment: CharField suites it

Comment: I'm getting the same exception, even with char field

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CharField` to store this information, as Hassan mentioned. You are getting this exception because although you might only *see* one character, "€" is stored encoded in the database. Increase the size of the field `currency_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)` from 3 to something greater than that.