# Django crashes when illegal characters are entered in a form?

Tags: django

I am giving the invalid `keyword` like this in a search form:

```
汉字/漢字
```

I use the search value to query in the database. I get the following exception:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/views.py" in search
  992.         if len(files) == 0:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  90.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  301.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  775.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  128.             six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  120.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  174.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /search/
Exception Value: (1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'")
```

How the handle this?

Comment: what's your database charset?

Comment: I am using MySQL. I just created a database using create database db_name so I think it took the default charset? How do I findout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql If it isn't utf8, drop it and create again w/ utf8 charset

Comment: character_set_database | latin1 and collation_database | latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: Instead of dropping and creating again, can't I just alter it?

Comment: I altered database and each table using the tutorial: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html
But still getting the same error.

Comment: and if you have a FRESH db with everything set to utf8, you got the same error about `latin1` again?

Comment: Didn't try with creating a new db. Just altered it, didn't work though.

Comment: Yes, I understood you altered existing DB and it didn't work. I'm just trying to help you and I need to know if it doesn't work even with new database created with unicode charset/collation etc. to identify the problem more precisely.

Comment: I created a new database and it worked with the new one.