# SQL Returns a Value but it doesn't appear in the Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, apostrophe

I have the following MySQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Results, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tresults WHERE q61 = 'Marketing') AS q1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tresults WHERE q61 = 'Account’s') AS q2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tresults WHERE q61 = 'Capital') AS q3,
FROM tresults
```

The output of which (within MySQL) is as follows:

```
Results    q1    Q2    Q3 
1327       12    6     8
```

I then use the following PHP code to place this information in an array:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $department = $row;
}
```

What is odd is when I var_dump or print_r $department the output is as follows:

```
Array ( [Results] => 1327 [q1] => 12 [q2] => 0 [q3] => 8 )
```

As you can see, if I run the query just in MySQL then q2 = 6 whereas when it is run the output and passed through to an array within PHP then q2 = 0?!?!?!?!

Now, I am wondering if it has something to do with the **apostrophe** ('Account**’**s'), you can see it is not an ordinary/ normal apostrophe.

Could this be causing the issue or is it my PHP code that places the SQL results into the array?

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: can't you escape it like `People\'s`?

Comment: Hi SuperDJ, I've tried - it doesn't need escaping as it runs through MySQL fine (as it returns 6 there) it's a different type of apostrophe.  In addition, it doesn't need escaping within the PHP.  i.e. it cause the string to break when escaped.

Comment: Should it not be `$department = $row3["q1"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it without the `while`?  I'd also eliminate the duplication of q1 (change `AS q1` to `AS q1Count`.  IMO it's bad practice to use a COUNT alias that matches an existing column name.

If that doesn't work, I'd start considering an encoding mismatch.  Two things to consider:

1. What is the encoding used by MySQL?
2. What is the encoding used by PHP's MySQLi?

```php
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS q1Count FROM results WHERE q1 = 'People’s'")
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
$count = $result['q1Count'];
```

To determine MySQL table encoding: `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME, DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

To set PHP MySQLi encoding: `$mysqli->set_charset("encoding here")`

Comment: I see you edited the post.  You may want to check the encoding (third thing I mentioned) since only the one segment of SQL is giving you trouble.

Comment: <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />

Comment: That's for HTML, not PHP.  If you don't have phpMyAdmin, you can run a query to check encoding as listed in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql).  Once you determine the encoding, you can use `$mysqli->set_charset("encoding here")` to load the correct character set.

Comment: I've now updated both PHP and MYSQL to use UTF 8...no joy.  This is driving me nuts!

Comment: It may or may not be UTF-8 (the other guy was making an assumption).  The link I provided explains how to get the correct encoding for the table.

Comment: Yep, on it.  Just checking now.

Comment: You can try setting the charset to `latin1` to see if that does anything.  If it doesn't work, you may need to explore the character sets of the environment in which the query *works* to find out what to do.  Then, there's always the issue of PHP encoding itself.  (This is why I generally use UTF8 for everything from databases to HTML and everything in between.  You want encodings to be consistent otherwise it leads to this sort of situation.)

Answer (score 0):

try running this query and see if it does what you want.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tresults WHERE q61 = 'Account’s'"
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$query = $mysqli->query($sql)
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $department = $row;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem a bit odd that the problem would be escaping given the SQL as written works in MySQL?  To me, this is indicative of an encoding issue, which would be consistent given the special character being used.

Comment: The page that is displaying the array is using the following: <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />

Comment: The `header` in PHP and `meta` in HTML won't fix the issue with count.  If you take a look at my answer (one above this answer), I explained how to find the MySQL character set, and set it in MySQLi.

Comment: Just added that, not working.  However, I notice that the charset is being set on mysql and I'm using mysqli?

Comment: @Homer_J sorry typo.. fixed :)

Comment: Two problems with the updated answer.  (1) UTF8 assumption is made, which may or may not be the case, (2) `mysql_set_charset()` is used, which should be `$mysqli->set_charset()`.  Rather than random shots in the dark, a purposeful check of the MySQL table will tell us the correct encoding.

Comment: OK, the collation is set to 'latin1_swedish_ci', apologies.

Comment: @webjawns.com the mysql_* was a typo.. and I already fixed it before you even commented.

Comment: So, looking at the encoding as follows:information_schema utf8
401_tsi latin1