# Illegal mix of collations maria db and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mariadb

I am facing an issue while inserting some characters into Maria DB.
I am using maria db connector 1.3.2 version.
Also suggest whether I should not insert the characters or any option to convert them into utf 8 characters

Hibernate properties:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc\:mariadb\://localhost\:3306/twitter?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
jdbc.username= root
jdbc.password = 
hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer = false
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl = false
hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf8
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf8
hibernate.connection.useUnicode = true
```

Below is log:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.dao.impl.RulesDAOImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesDAOImpl.java:69)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(Unknown Source)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.service.impl.RulesServiceImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesServiceImpl.java:50)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRuleToInfoarmorSchema(RulesOperations.java:98)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRule(RulesOperations.java:51)
    com.infoarmor.v1.controller.RulesController.add(RulesController.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.execute(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:376)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:343)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.dao.impl.RulesDAOImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesDAOImpl.java:69)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(Unknown Source)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.service.impl.RulesServiceImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesServiceImpl.java:50)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRuleToInfoarmorSchema(RulesOperations.java:98)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRule(RulesOperations.java:51)
    com.infoarmor.v1.controller.RulesController.add(RulesController.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
    org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:136)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:338)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:293)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.execute(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:371)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:343)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.dao.impl.RulesDAOImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesDAOImpl.java:69)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(Unknown Source)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.service.impl.RulesServiceImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesServiceImpl.java:50)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRuleToInfoarmorSchema(RulesOperations.java:98)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRule(RulesOperations.java:51)
    com.infoarmor.v1.controller.RulesController.add(RulesController.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
    org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:478)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executePreparedQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:591)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:281)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.execute(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:371)
    org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:343)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.dao.impl.RulesDAOImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesDAOImpl.java:69)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(Unknown Source)
    com.infoarmor.twitter.service.service.impl.RulesServiceImpl.findByStreamAndValueOrTag(RulesServiceImpl.java:50)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRuleToInfoarmorSchema(RulesOperations.java:98)
    com.infoarmor.rules.operations.RulesOperations.addRule(RulesOperations.java:51)
    com.infoarmor.v1.controller.RulesController.add(RulesController.java:91)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Don't confuse collations with character sets. A Collation is a rule for ordering characters. Different languages may have different ordering on their letters (e.g. ordering of accented versions of the same letter, mixing of non-latin letters with latin letters etc.). When you are comparing a column that has a certain collation with a column that has a different collation, this causes a conflict.

Comment: What collations are you using in the database?  See [How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is)

Comment: Using utf8_general_ci collation

Comment: there seems to be a table with latin1_swedish_ci collation: wich tables/columns are used in the query? Specificly wich are compared with '=' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created table by mentioning utf8_general_ci but it created with latin1_swedish_ci. Altering the table solved issue. 
Thanks a lot.

alter collation script:
alter table table_name convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;