# Aqua Data Studio UTF-8 Support ('é' shows as 'Ã©')

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, aqua-data-studio

#### Situation

I have a lot of UTF-8 characters saved in a MySQL database.

In PHP, I do this:

```
SELECT name FROM institutions;
```

The characters display correctly with no problems and no additional processing necessary within the query or within the PHP script.

In Aqua Data Studio 16.0.9 I'm having a bit of a problem displaying UTF-8 characters. Instead of `Å` it displays as `Ã…`, instead of `é` it displays as `Ã©` and so on.

What I've tried so far are in terms of the query itself:

1. `SELECT CONVERT(name USING utf8) FROM institutions;`
2. `SET NAMES 'utf8'; SELECT name FROM institutions;`
3. A combination of the solutions above.
4. Changed the font of Aqua Data Studio to a font that supports UTF-8 like `Verdana`, `Arial`, etc.

So far none of what I did worked.

#### Questions

- How do I support UTF-8 in Aqua Data Studio 16.0.9?
- Can I instead of doing the fix in the query itself, just configure Aqua Data Studio so that any other queries in the future are UTF-8 compatible?

#### Edit

I also tried adding `?characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the `Driver Parameters` under the `Server Properties` window and still I can't get it to display the characters correctly.

Comment: Is this Java-based?  Or php-based?

Comment: @RickJames You mean the software? Aqua Data Studio is made with Java.

Answer (score 2):

Mojibake.  Usually...

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

Comment: The [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is/1049958#1049958) tells me how to check the character set at the `schema`, `table`, and `column` levels. When I ran those, the `schema` is set to `latin1`, the `table` is set to `utf8` and the `column` is set to `utf8` as well.

Comment: I also tried adding `?characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the `Driver Parameters` under the `Server Properties` window and still I can't get it to display the characters correctly.

Comment: In ADS it should be ?characterEncoding=utf8

Comment: @tariq I tried `?characterEncoding=utf8` as well and it still doesn't display properly.

Comment: @tariq Maybe the characters aren't `UTF-8`?

Comment: @RickJames I have that set to true by default. I even tried doing `?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true` under the driver parameters and it still wouldn't display properly.

Comment: Can you check your query results in the MySQL command line tool ? Is the results different from Aqua Data Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure to have these 3 lines in your my.conf :

collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8

In ADS v16 Server Properties, you can override the default connection to force utf8 by setting:
?characterEncoding=utf8

Comment: Where can I find the `my.conf`?