# How to select default collation value for database server

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to select the default collation of a database server value using php code. So far I was able to accomplish it using the following select statement. But when the default collation value was changed by me the result of the query remained the same. However I want this to be able to select from both mySQL and MariaDB while having a robust method to do this thanks.

```
$sql = 'SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME ='.'"information_schema"';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is)

Answer (score 0):

The "default" `CHARACTER SET` for the database is just that, a "default".  It is used only(?) when you do `CREATE TABLE` without specifying a `CHARACTER SET` *on the create table*.

So, don't bother with it.  Instead, explicitly specify the charset on `CREATE TABLE`.

But, then, *that* is just a *default* for each char/text column.

(Ditto for `COLLATION`.)