# Indexing Euro (€) and Lb (£) in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

These don't seem to index, even when I explicitly add them to my charset_table:

```
charset_table=...  U+20AC->U+20AC, U+00A3->U+00A3
```

I even tried mapping them to the dollar sign

```
U+0024->U+0024, U+20AC->U+0024, U+00A3->U+0024
```

Yet in each case they are unrecognized in other words `MATCH('£1000')` will not find 'cost is £1000' and if I try to map to `$` as per the second example then `MATCH('$1000`)` will not either.

If I do a MySQL Search however `where field like '%£%'` I do get records leading me to believe the MySQL is encoding UTF-8 correctly. Meaning the `Pound Sign` and `Euro` characters are being stored correctly in MySQL but the Sphinx index is not recognizing them regardless, even after I explicitly add their Unicode characters to my `charset_table`.

Relevant portion of config:

```
`min_stemming_len = 1
stopword_step = 0
html_strip  = 1
min_word_len = 1
min_infix_len = 0
index_zones = title,description
charset_type = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+0026->U+0026, U+0027->U+0027, U+002E->U+002E, U+002D->U+002D, U+2014->U+002D#, U+2019->U+0027, U+0024->U+0024, U+20AC->U+0024, U+00A3->U+0024
```

Confirmed that the table/column is using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Confirmed I can do a mysql search on Euro: `Where Title like '%€%'`

Confirmed I cannot find same record with SphinxQL: `where MATCH('€')`

Answer (score 0):

There are a three  things you should check:

**First**,  look at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is) to check your MySQL char encoding;

**Secondly**, look in your Sphinx config to check `charset_type` matches it.

**Lastly**, remember, after any changes to `charset_type` or `charset_table` you need to rebuild indexes.

If none of the above helps, you could post your Sphinx Config here, which might give further clues as to the problem.

Comment: Greller Ok I did check char encoding and in fact for the table/column in question changed from `utf8mb4_general_ci` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` based on comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci that "general fails fails to implement all of the Unicode sorting rules.. such as when using particular languages or characters." I also then, in addition to specifying the charset_table for the Euro also specified chaset_type. No luck. Yet MysQl search for Euro Symbol still works.