# Sphinx exact match to column string

Tags: sphinx

I thought that

```
Match('^Word$')
```

Would only find records that are exactly 'Word'

However although this does work for single words it does not for mutliple:

```
Match ('^Final Word$')
```

Finds 'Final Word' and 'Final and Last Word'.

as does

```
Match ('^"Final Word"$')
```

How do I tell Sphinx to only find an exact match?

---

Update: After some testing the *best* I can do is weighting/ranker and w/o ""

```
MATCH('^Final Word$') order by weight() desc limit 1 desc  OPTION ranker=PROXIMITY_BM25
```

So I forced an exact match with ranking and limit, still would be nice to know how to actually say 'only return exact matches'.

One issue with above is if I do *not* have 'Final Word' in the table it will find all others e.g. 'Final and Last Word' which is behavior I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You just got your operators in wrong order :)

```
Match('"^Final Word$ "')
```

(having a space after $ helps with some mysterious sphinx bug!)

Comment: That way returns zero results regardless of matches for some reason.

Comment: What version of sphinx? Try with a space after the $, there was a bug in some versions, that would mysterilly not work! I tried to put that in my reply above, but did it worng!

Comment: @BarrHunter I don't suppose you want to give this question a whirl?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381060/indexing-euro-%E2%82%AC-and-lb-%C2%A3-in-sphinx

Comment: My version is `Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)` The `"^Final Word$"` definitely fails as does `"^Final Word$ "`

Comment: I probably know less about charsets than you.

Comment: This turns out to be unsolvable to date and is in fact breaking my entire search. `"^Final Word$"` still finds nothing and `^Final Word$` find results like `Final Other Words Word`. If Sphinx can't find an exact match in my case all the other work is for naught.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue turned out to be that in my efforts to make this work one step had been to specify the ranker

`Option Ranker=PROXIMITY_BM25`

which had worked for me up to then. What actually works is

`Match('^Final Word$')`

and then not specifying ranker or specifying `extended` if the ranker in config is defined otherwise (it is `extended` by default).