# Spanish text are not displaying properly in browser

Tags: php, mysql

hi Guys i'm working on a website in which some of the text is in Spanish but when i tried to fetch them in browser they look like this

[image]

is there any way to solve this with php or html meta tags..i tried using
php function and meta tags below here but No diffrence at all

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT='utf8'",$connect);
mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS='utf8'",$connect);
mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION='utf8'",$connect);
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

htmlspecialchars_decode();
html_entity_decode();

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

please help!

Comment: this is a typo'd post. The connection comes first. Edit: The duplicate contains the correct syntax and much more.

Comment: The first step is checking in what characterset the data is stored in the database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is and go from there

Comment: thank sir ,i just solved this