# Mysql is showing question mark for UTF-8 characters?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

I have a table **linkmapper** with a single column **keyword**.
Table collation is **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**.
I tried to execute the following command.

```
insert into linkmapper (keyword) values("There’s is a demo");
```

Later I used the select command to see the content of the table.

```
mysql> select keyword from linkmapper;
+-------------------+
| keyword           |
+-------------------+
| There?s is a demo |
+-------------------+
```

Here you can see that special character is replaced by **?**.

**PS:** This problem is just arising on my localhost WAMP machine. On production, everything is working as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is)

Comment: Hi, Already mentioned charset and collation. It does not answer.

Comment: Did you type `SET names utf8mb4` first?

Comment: @Evert Now getting this after setting as you said.
mysql> select keyword from linkmapper limit 1;
+---------------------+
| keyword             |
+---------------------+
| ThereÔÇÖs is a demo |
+---------------------+

Comment: What terminal application are you viewing this in? Is it configured for utf-8?

Comment: Mysql console from wamp

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the encoding, maybe using `utf8_general_ci` can solve it.

How to do it: https://www.a2hosting.com.br/kb/developer-corner/mysql/convert-mysql-database-utf-8

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Collations don't deal with encoding; Character sets do.